# UIButton action in Collection Header View Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have one button in header cell that created by IB. I add on action, but I can not trigger. This code;

```
 func collectionView( _ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    switch kind {

    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "sectionHeader", for: indexPath) as! ProfilePhotoHeaderCell
        cell.lblFavCount.text = user.favdCount
        let countFoto = ((user.photos?.count)!)
        cell.lblFotoCount.text = countFoto.description
        cell.btnAddPhotos.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        cell.btnAddPhotos?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ProfileController.myAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)  // add selector
        return cell
    case IOStickyHeaderParallaxHeader:
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerCell1", for: indexPath) as! ProfileParallaxHeaderCell

        return headerView
    default:
        assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")

    }


       }
```

Comment: try cell.userInteractionEnabled = true

Comment: I tried but it wasn't working. I add button programmatically in subview 
it works. But I want to use IB because of constraints.